# Can the sound change the state of the medium?

Tags: thermodynamics, acoustics, states-of-matter

The waves perform compression and rarefraccion in the medium where they spread, right?

when the rarefraction happens we should feel the medium in a liquid or gaseous state since the molecules expand and when the compression happens we should feel the medium in a solid state since the molecules are compressed.

Comment: You might be interested in [sonoluminescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonoluminescence).

Comment: And also in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavitation (though that changes the medium between liquid and gas, but not  to solid)

Comment: think of singers breaking crystal . https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oc27GxSD_bI  ( but it is not the molecules that expand, the distance between them on the lattice changes as the sound wave passes)

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that compression and rarefaction occur in the medium "sound" as it is usually described is a small perturbation about a background density and pressure.  Also, there are assumptions on the thermodynamics state variable of the fluid medium that constrain the behavior of the material under these perturbations.  One can drive waves with very high amplitude, creating non-linear waves, and these may cause such effects.  But one could argue that this is not formally "sound" since you've created circumstances that violate the assumptions leading to the acoustic wave equation derived form the equations of fluid dynamics.

Comment: Circumstances violate the assumptions that lead to the acoustic wave equation derived from fluid dynamics equations?
What circumstances are you talking about?

Comment: what about resonances as in crystal breaking? The frequencies are inherent in the mathematical description of sound

Comment: @molo32, I mentioned an example of non-linear acoustics, they do not obey the wave equation.

Comment: @annav, I am not sure how your comment about breaking a glass has to do with the peaks and troughs in the acoustic wave in air changing the state of the fluid, which is my interpretation of the OP.  While it is true that hitting the resonance frequency of the glass may cause it to crack fracture dynamics is a different subject.  Are you implying that to cause fracture you need to liquefy the glass along the fracture line?

Comment: Under ordinary conditions as sound propagates through a medium the medium state is not changed from solid to liquid, though I see no reason why this cannot happen in extraordinary conditions, e.g. non-linear high amplitude acoustics.